# slimMenu Breaking Zen Cart

Tags: php, jquery, css, jquery-cookie

So this may be a shot in the dark but wondering if anyone smarter than I can tell me why the slimMenu breaks when I add these files to the bottom of the page.

```
<link href="includes/templates/westminster_new/css/age-verification.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="includes/templates/westminster_new/jscript/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="includes/templates/westminster_new/jscript/age-verification.js"></script>
<script src="includes/templates/westminster_new/jscript/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

This is the whole page:

```
<?php
/**
 * Common Template
 *
 * outputs the html header. i,e, everything that comes before the \</head\> tag <br />
 *
 * @package templateSystem
 * @copyright Copyright 2003-2014 Zen Cart Development Team
 * @copyright Portions Copyright 2003 osCommerce
 * @license http://www.zen-cart.com/license/2_0.txt GNU Public License V2.0
 * @version GIT: $Id: Author: DrByte  Jul 5 2014 Modified in v1.5.4 $
 * Altered by rbarbour (ZCAdditions.com), Responsive DIY Template Default for 1.5.x (65)
 * Modified by Anne (Picaflor-Azul.com) Westminster New v1.3
 */
/**
 * load the module for generating page meta-tags
 */
require(DIR_WS_MODULES . zen_get_module_directory('meta_tags.php'));
/**
 * output main page HEAD tag and related headers/meta-tags, etc
 */
?>


<?php
// (BOF - 2.1) Responsive DIY Template Default for 1.5.x (65)   

if (!class_exists('Mobile_Detect')) {
include_once(DIR_WS_CLASSES . 'Mobile_Detect.php'); 
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
}

// (EOF - 2.1) Responsive DIY Template Default for 1.5.x (65)   
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php echo HTML_PARAMS; ?>>
<head>
<title><?php echo META_TAG_TITLE; ?></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php echo CHARSET; ?>" />
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo META_TAG_KEYWORDS; ?>" />
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo META_TAG_DESCRIPTION; ?>" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<meta name="author" content="The Zen Cart&reg; Team. Responsive zen cart design by Picaflor Azul. " />
<meta name="generator" content="shopping cart program by Zen Cart&reg;, http://www.zen-cart.com eCommerce" />

<?php // (BOF - 2.1) Responsive DIY Template Default for 1.5.x (65) ?>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

<?php // (EOF - 2.1) Responsive DIY Template Default for 1.5.x (65) ?>

<?php if (defined('ROBOTS_PAGES_TO_SKIP') && in_array($current_page_base,explode(",",constant('ROBOTS_PAGES_TO_SKIP'))) || $current_page_base=='down_for_maintenance' || $robotsNoIndex === true) { ?>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<?php } ?>
<?php if (defined('FAVICON')) { ?>
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo FAVICON; ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo FAVICON; ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<?php } //endif FAVICON ?>

<base href="<?php echo (($request_type == 'SSL') ? HTTPS_SERVER . DIR_WS_HTTPS_CATALOG : HTTP_SERVER . DIR_WS_CATALOG ); ?>" />
<?php if (isset($canonicalLink) && $canonicalLink != '') { ?>
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $canonicalLink; ?>" />
<?php } ?>

<?php
/**
 * load all template-specific stylesheets, named like "style*.css", alphabetically
 */
  $directory_array = $template->get_template_part($template->get_template_dir('.css',DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base,'css'), '/^style/', '.css');
  while(list ($key, $value) = each($directory_array)) {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $template->get_template_dir('.css',DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base,'css') . '/' . $value . '" />'."\n";
  }
/**
 * load stylesheets on a per-page/per-language/per-product/per-manufacturer/per-category basis. Concept by Juxi Zoza.
 */
  $manufacturers_id = (isset($_GET['manufacturers_id'])) ? $_GET['manufacturers_id'] : '';
  $tmp_products_id = (isset($_GET['products_id'])) ? (int)$_GET['products_id'] : '';
  $tmp_pagename = ($this_is_home_page) ? 'index_home' : $current_page_base;
  if ($current_page_base == 'page' && isset($ezpage_id)) $tmp_pagename = $current_page_base . (int)$ezpage_id;
  $sheets_array = array('/' . $_SESSION['language'] . '_stylesheet',
                        '/' . $tmp_pagename,
                        '/' . $_SESSION['language'] . '_' . $tmp_pagename,
                        '/c_' . $cPath,
                        '/' . $_SESSION['language'] . '_c_' . $cPath,
                        '/m_' . $manufacturers_id,
                        '/' . $_SESSION['language'] . '_m_' . (int)$manufacturers_id,
                        '/p_' . $tmp_products_id,
                        '/' . $_SESSION['language'] . '_p_' . $tmp_products_id
                        );
  while(list ($key, $value) = each($sheets_array)) {
    //echo "<!--looking for: $value-->\n";
    $perpagefile = $template->get_template_dir('.css', DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base, 'css') . $value . '.css';
    if (file_exists($perpagefile)) echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $perpagefile .'" />'."\n";
  }

/**
 *  custom category handling for a parent and all its children ... works for any c_XX_XX_children.css  where XX_XX is any parent category
 */
  $tmp_cats = explode('_', $cPath);
  $value = '';
  foreach($tmp_cats as $val) {
    $value .= $val;
    $perpagefile = $template->get_template_dir('.css', DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base, 'css') . '/c_' . $value . '_children.css';
    if (file_exists($perpagefile)) echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $perpagefile .'" />'."\n";
    $perpagefile = $template->get_template_dir('.css', DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base, 'css') . '/' . $_SESSION['language'] . '_c_' . $value . '_children.css';
    if (file_exists($perpagefile)) echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $perpagefile .'" />'."\n";
    $value .= '_';
  }

/**
 * load printer-friendly stylesheets -- named like "print*.css", alphabetically
 */
  $directory_array = $template->get_template_part($template->get_template_dir('.css',DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base,'css'), '/^print/', '.css');
  sort($directory_array);
  while(list ($key, $value) = each($directory_array)) {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="' . $template->get_template_dir('.css',DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base,'css') . '/' . $value . '" />'."\n";
  }

/**
 * load all site-wide jscript_*.js files from includes/templates/YOURTEMPLATE/jscript, alphabetically
 */
  $directory_array = $template->get_template_part($template->get_template_dir('.js',DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base,'jscript'), '/^jscript_/', '.js');
  while(list ($key, $value) = each($directory_array)) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' .  $template->get_template_dir('.js',DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base,'jscript') . '/' . $value . '"></script>'."\n";
  }

  /** CDN for jQuery core **/
?>
<script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write(unescape('%3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'));</script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write(unescape('%3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $template->get_template_dir('.js',DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base,'jscript'); ?>/jquery.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'));</script>

<?php
/**
 * load all page-specific jscript_*.js files from includes/modules/pages/PAGENAME, alphabetically
 */
  $directory_array = $template->get_template_part($page_directory, '/^jscript_/', '.js');
  while(list ($key, $value) = each($directory_array)) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . $page_directory . '/' . $value . '"></script>' . "\n";
  }

/**
 * load all site-wide jscript_*.php files from includes/templates/YOURTEMPLATE/jscript, alphabetically
 */
  $directory_array = $template->get_template_part($template->get_template_dir('.php',DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base,'jscript'), '/^jscript_/', '.php');
  while(list ($key, $value) = each($directory_array)) {
/**
 * include content from all site-wide jscript_*.php files from includes/templates/YOURTEMPLATE/jscript, alphabetically.
 * These .PHP files can be manipulated by PHP when they're called, and are copied in-full to the browser page
 */
    require($template->get_template_dir('.php',DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base,'jscript') . '/' . $value); echo "\n";
  }
/**
 * include content from all page-specific jscript_*.php files from includes/modules/pages/PAGENAME, alphabetically.
 */
  $directory_array = $template->get_template_part($page_directory, '/^jscript_/');
  while(list ($key, $value) = each($directory_array)) {
/**
 * include content from all page-specific jscript_*.php files from includes/modules/pages/PAGENAME, alphabetically.
 * These .PHP files can be manipulated by PHP when they're called, and are copied in-full to the browser page
 */
    require($page_directory . '/' . $value); echo "\n";
  }

// DEBUG: echo '<!-- I SEE cat: ' . $current_category_id . ' || vs cpath: ' . $cPath . ' || page: ' . $current_page . ' || template: ' . $current_template . ' || main = ' . ($this_is_home_page ? 'YES' : 'NO') . ' -->';


// (BOF - 2.1) Responsive DIY Template Default for 1.5.x (65)   

if (COLUMN_WIDTH == '0' || (in_array($current_page_base,explode(",",'popup_image,popup_image_additional')) )) {  

    echo '';

} else {
$responsive_mobile = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $template->get_template_dir('.css',DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base,'css') . '/' . 'responsive_mobile.css' . '" />'; 
require($template->get_template_dir('responsive_mobile.php',DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base,'common'). '/responsive_mobile.php');

$responsive_tablet = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $template->get_template_dir('.css',DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base,'css') . '/' . 'responsive_tablet.css' . '" />'; 
require($template->get_template_dir('responsive_tablet.php',DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base,'common'). '/responsive_tablet.php');

$responsive_default = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $template->get_template_dir('.css',DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base,'css') . '/' . 'responsive_default.css' . '" />'; 

echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $template->get_template_dir('.css',DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base,'css') . '/' . 'responsive.css' . '" />';

if ($detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet() or $detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet() && $_SESSION['display_mode']=='isMobile' or $detect->isTablet() && $_SESSION['display_mode']=='isMobile' or $_SESSION['display_mode']=='isMobile') {

    echo $responsive_mobile;


} else if ($detect->isTablet() or $detect->isMobile() && $_SESSION['display_mode']=='isTablet' or $detect->isTablet() && $_SESSION['display_mode']=='isTablet' or $_SESSION['display_mode']=='isTablet'){

    echo $responsive_tablet;


} else if ($detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet() && $_SESSION['display_mode']=='isDesktop' or $detect->isTablet() && $_SESSION['display_mode']=='isDesktop' or $_SESSION['display_mode']=='isNonResponsive'){

    echo '';

} else {

    echo $responsive_default;

  }  
}

if($detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet() && $_SESSION['display_mode']=='isDesktop' or $detect->isTablet() && $_SESSION['display_mode']=='isDesktop' or $detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet() && $_SESSION['display_mode']=='isNonResponsive' or $detect->isTablet() && $_SESSION['display_mode']=='isNonResponsive' or $_SESSION['display_mode']=='isNonResponsive'){
$fluidisFixed = 'fluidIsFixed';
} else {
$fluidisFixed = '';
}
// (EOF - 2.1) Responsive DIY Template Default for 1.5.x (65)   
?>

<script src="<?php echo $template->get_template_dir('',DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base,'jscript') . '/css_browser_selector.js' ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="includes/templates/westminster_new/css/age-verification.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="includes/templates/westminster_new/jscript/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="includes/templates/westminster_new/jscript/age-verification.js"></script>
<script src="includes/templates/westminster_new/jscript/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>



</head>
<?php // NOTE: Blank line following is intended: ?>
```

Comment: Looks like there is a semicolon missing: `...'/css_browser_selector.js'; ?>"...`. If this is not it, then please show only the "compiled" html output.

Comment: I appreciate the input but the ";" wasn't the problem/solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jquery is being included twice as ZC loads it above the new lines you're adding.

Comment: You may wish to point at the lines where that happens and propose a fix.